# "Owner" - not a room attribute?

Tags: rocket.chat

Out of curiosity - why [room schema](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/schema-definition/), in particular:

```
  "u": {                                   // Object           Owner User
"_id": "CABrXSHpDqbZXGkYR",            // Random.id()      User Id
"username": "john"                     // String           User Username }
```

defines a "u" as an owner while in fact - this is the creator?

I mean - why the owner is to be retrieved from [subscription object](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/method-calls/get-subscriptions/) and cannot be a part of "room"?

This leads to a problem when we want to fetch all channels (*open rooms*) where a used has not explicitly joined yet, meaning - there is no subscription.

Do you have any recommendation apart from hacking the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don;t realy understand why it leads to problems. Simple fetch [all channels](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/list/) and remove [the channels the user has joined](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/list-joined/).

Comment: Thx for suggestion Robin. I still do think this is a kind-of a workaround though - assuming we are calling the APIs from the mobile app, that leads to quite some overheads on the network.

Anyways - would it be ok if I put a pull-request for the docs to adjust "Owner" to "Creator"?

Comment: I won't know since I'm not a RC developer, but you could always try.